# SharePoint Search Find Records between a date range

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

This is my try to get records below the date:

SELECT Title, XXXX from scope() where "scope" ='XYZScope' AND XYZDate < 1/1/2007 12:00:00 AM

It says "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E07"

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dates need to be in a different format: [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Example:

```
2008-10-13T14:05:31-05:00
```

I was never able to get the ESSQL to work with dates that had their time component still on but I have something working using the days.

Your query should be something like:

```
SELECT Title, XXXX from scope() where "scope" ='XYZScope' AND XYZDate < '2007-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477432.aspx) operator. For example:

SELECT WorkId,Path,Title,Write,Author FROM Scope()
WHERE XYZDate < DATEADD(DAY,30,GETGMTDATE())

Comment: DATEADD doesn't support positive values for offset.MSDN Says:

"OffsetValue

Specifies the time offset, in the units specified by the DateTimeUnits parameter. OffsetValue must be a negative integer. Positive values are not supported."

Answer (score 0):

try:

SELECT Title, XXXX from scope() where "scope" ='XYZScope' AND XYZDate <= '2007-01-01 12:00:00'

FullTextSqlQuery.Execute will always return nothing if you omit the time element.  Another way may be to do something like

... XYZDate between date1 and '2007-01-01 12:00:00'

where date1 is a string represnetation of Date.MinValue

The culture (i.e. regional settings) of all servers in your farm also need to match in order for the statements to work.